# How can i make my content iframe responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem, i can't resize my iframe to be fully responsive (I mean, the content!)

```
<iframe src="https://www.meteoblue.com/fr/meteo/widget/three/saint-jean-de-braye_france_2979341?geoloc=fixed&nocurrent=0&noforecast=0&days=4&tempunit=CELSIUS&windunit=KILOMETER_PER_HOUR&layout=image"  frameborder="0" scrolling="NO" allowtransparency="true" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" style="width: 460px;height: 594px">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making an iframe responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838607/making-an-iframe-responsive)

Comment: I tried some answers of this topic, with no luck, unfortunatly..

Comment: The iframe itself will be responsive, you can find your answer there or some other SO questions of similar issues, but the content / url from which you are fetching your page has to be responsive too. otherwise you'll only see your iframe shrinking and expanding, not the content inside.

Comment: Ok I thought there was a way (in JS maybe) too override some limitations...

Comment: No, there isn't. JS can modify contents within a page, not from another page / source. if you own the page which you are fetching with iframe, you can make that page responsive. There is no other way.

Comment: This might be something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819383/how-to-make-the-contents-inside-an-iframe-responsive

Comment: Thx for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```css
.iframe-container{
max-width:700px;
width:100%;
margin:0 auto
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-container">
<iframe src="https://www.meteoblue.com/fr/meteo/widget/three/saint-jean-de-braye_france_2979341?geoloc=fixed&nocurrent=0&noforecast=0&days=4&tempunit=CELSIUS&windunit=KILOMETER_PER_HOUR&layout=image"  frameborder="0" scrolling="NO" allowtransparency="true" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" style="width: 100%;height: 594px"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes actually there is a min-width set inside iframe  .wrapper.count-4 {
 min-width: 440px;
 max-width: 520px;
}

this is causing the problem.
Can u remove the min-width property or set it to 320px instead of 440px

Comment: Yes! I saw that, but it's not my iframe so i cant't iteract with .wrapper.count-4...